# interface showing "Link not connected" on a Nexus 2200 FEX but it is very much connected

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-nexus

I have to be over looking something dumb here but I can't figure it out.

The fex is set up properly and is communicating to the Nexus 5548 without issue. There are a few other fexs connected as well.

The interface config is bare bones at this point:

```
interface fex100/1/1
  switchport access vlan xx
  spanning-tree port type edge
  no shut
```

I have tried to plug other devices into the port and no link lights will come up. No errors are shown in the log. I have connected to the server via its Ethernet port from a directly connected laptop and its link lights come up no problem.

The vlan is already on the switch as well.

A show interface shows that zero traffic has crossed the link.

If there is any other information I could provide please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out the upstream 5k was in a pair so I needed to make the interface config change on both 5ks. Problem solved.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as correct to close the question out.  Thank you for your follow-up.

Comment: I have to wait 48 hours to do that.